# Wrapping slider in div decreasing height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

Im using this slider .
Here is demo link

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos/main-demos/17-responsive.html

but I want to wrap this slider in a div but when i do it decreases the height to 125px from 100%

original code

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide blue-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide orange-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide green-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide pink-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide blue-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide orange-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
```

my code:

```
<div class="bodycontent">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide blue-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide orange-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide green-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide pink-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide blue-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide orange-slide">
        <div class="title">Slide 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it's height is set to 100%, you need to set the height of the parent element you are adding, otherwise it doesn't know what 100% means. Add `.bodycontent{height:100%;}` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Just mark the question as answered--'accept' the answer Brewal offered below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this CSS:

```
.bodycontent {
    height: 100%
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it--what Brewal said.